# Using ci merchant for CodeIgniter how to integrate stripe payment gateway

Tags: php, codeigniter, stripe-payments

Using ci merchant for CodeIgniter.  How to integrate Stripe payment gateway, and how to pass in `default_settings()` and in `purchase()` method?
I have tried Google but did not find anything helpful.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

ci-merchant is not maintained anymore. Use [Omnipay](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay) instead

Comment: https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-stripe  how it is used for codeigniter project or there is any other code for codeigniter project

Comment: Did you install omnipay/stripe by composer ?

Answer (score 0):

-> Below Code is working good for me

```
$this->load->library('merchant');
$this->merchant->load('stripe');

$token = array('number' => '4242424242424242', 'exp_month' => 8, 'exp_year' => 2018);

$params = array(
    'token' => $token,
    'amount' => 100.00,
    'currency' => 'USD',
);

$response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);
```